# Should :name and/or :app be added to project definition in root mix.exs file in umbrella application?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, ex-doc

I'm attempting to generate documentation for applications in my Elixir project using ExDoc. My project is structured as an umbrella application, with two apps, a functional core and a Phoenix web frontend. When running the command `mix docs` from the root of the umbrella, I get the following error message:

```
** (RuntimeError) expected :name or :app to be found in the project definition in mix.exs
    (ex_doc 0.23.0) lib/mix/tasks/docs.ex:328: Mix.Tasks.Docs.run/3
    (mix 1.11.3) lib/mix/task.ex:394: Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix 1.11.3) lib/mix/cli.ex:84: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
    (elixir 1.11.3) lib/code.ex:931: Code.require_file/2
```

The root mix.exs file is as follows:

```
defmodule UmbrellaProject.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      apps_path: "apps",
      version: "0.1.0",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  defp deps do
    [{:ex_doc, "~> 0.23.0", dev: true, runtime: false}]
  end
end
```

Should I add :name and/or :app values to the list in the `project/1` function? If yes, is there a standard convention for what their values should be or can they be anything (within reason)?

I'm using Elixir version 1.11.3.

Comment: I'm not sure if the `version` should be there. Can you remove it and try again?

Comment: @DavidMagalhães Thanks for the suggestion, however it did not fix the problem. Why shouldn’t there be a `version` in the root mix.exs? It was put there by the mix umbrella generator

Comment: I have a umbrella project here that didn't have it. I thought that if a version exists it may expect a name.

Comment: That’s interesting. ExDoc works for you in your `:name`-less project? And the only difference is a lack of a version?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `name: " xxx "`  in your config.

```
defmodule UmbrellaProject.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      name: "My umbrella project",
      apps_path: "apps",
      version: "0.1.0",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  defp deps do
    [{:ex_doc, "~> 0.23.0", dev: true, runtime: false}]
  end
end
```